# How to use operations in Google Sheets when referencing another sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to know how to get the min and max from a sheet into another sheet. Example:
my Sheet1 has this data:
[image]

And I would like to reference sheet 1 in sheet 2 to get the max and min number of orders for each item

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do try

```
=QUERY(L1:M9, 
    "select L, min(M), max(M) where L<>'' 
     group by L 
     label min(M) 'Min order', max(M) 'Max order' ",1)
```

[image]

As an alternative you can use

```
={MINIFS(M2:M,L2:L,"="&O3),MAXIFS(M2:M,L2:L,"="&O3)}
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [`MINIFS`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7014063)
- [`MAXIFS`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013817)

Comment: How would you reference the sheets in this case if you have a lot of data and cant put them on one sheet?

Comment: And how would you have the formula if you wanted to do both Hair Ties and Pins?

Comment: *"How would you reference..."* Sorry. I lost you. *"And how would you... "* have you tried the formulas?

Comment: Thank you, I got it!